# More efficent way to place widgets in screen - Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, frontend

I am building a screen that has data from some math problems, but I'm new to Flutter and for me seems very complicated to place things in fixed places without doing a mess since I don't know a bunch of widgets that can help me, and I'm pretty sure there's an easier way to do this screen, so I want to ask if someone can help me with this.

This screen is the result I want

[image]

And this is the code I made:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProblemsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProblemsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ProblemsScreen> createState() => _ProblemsScreenState();
}

class _ProblemsScreenState extends State<ProblemsScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Problem title',
            style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 30,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300
            ),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
      ),

      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child:Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            
            //Timer counter
            const Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text('00:00')
              ],
            ),

            //Timer Icon
            const Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.timer)
              ],
            ),

            //Problem data, will be a long string later
            const Center(
              child: Text('Problem data'),
            ),
      
            //Button grid with a label
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                const Text('Select an asnwer'), //Label

                //Button grid
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            TextButton(onPressed: (){}, child: const Text('Answer 1')), 
                            TextButton(onPressed: (){}, child: const Text('Answer 2')),                               
                          ]
                        ),

                        Row(
                          children: [
                            TextButton(onPressed: (){}, child: const Text('Answer 3')), 
                            TextButton(onPressed: (){}, child: const Text('Answer 4')),                               
                          ]
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, it is completly a mess beacuse of `stack-row-column` tricks I did and I find it complex to maintain, can someone show me a different way to do it?

Comment: `Row` is meant for having multiple children. I wouldn't use it when it only has one child. You could use `Align` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `widgets` or `helper methods`.
You don't have to use Stack as Container widget. Container widget can be column because the layout is going top to bottom.
And refer to Ivo's comment, you can use Align instead Row.

refactored code is like below

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const ProblemsScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class ProblemsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProblemsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ProblemsScreen> createState() => _ProblemsScreenState();
}

class _ProblemsScreenState extends State<ProblemsScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Problem title',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            _buildTimer(),
            const Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Problem data'),
              ),
            ),
            _buildAnswers(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTimer() {
    return const Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        Text('00:00', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
        Align(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child: Icon(Icons.timer)),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildAnswers() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
          TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Answer 1')),
          TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Answer 2')),
        ],),
        Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
          TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Answer 3')),
          TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Answer 4')),
        ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

There is a [official video](https://youtu.be/IOyq-eTRhvo) for this.

- widgets

  - it requires more boilerplate code, but Flutter can optimize rendering speed.
  - widget can be constant.
- helper methods

  - you can write less code.
  - easier to access parent field.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to position your widgets inside a screen you can use Stack and Alignments to poisition your widget. Here is the code for your help

```
Container(
      height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child:Stack(
          children: <Widget>[

            //Timer counter
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Text('00:00'),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: Icon(Icons.timer),
            ),

            //Problem data, will be a long string later
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text('Problem data'),
            ),

            //Button grid with a label
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  const Text('Select an asnwer'), //Label
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        TextButton(onPressed: (){}, child: const Text('Answer 1')),
                        TextButton(onPressed: (){}, child: const Text('Answer 2')),
                      ]
                  ),
                  Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        TextButton(onPressed: (){}, child: const Text('Answer 2')),
                        TextButton(onPressed: (){}, child: const Text('Answer 3')),
                      ]
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            )

          ],
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure you're using is actually not that bad, but if you want to look at another approach you might want to look at FlutterFlow

[FlutterFlow Homepage](https://flutterflow-io.translate.goog/?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=de&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=sc)

This way you won't have to deal with this kind of code.